# Change color of Pathlayer on Click, MapBox DeckGl React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mapbox, deck.gl

I have a **mapbox** **React.js** component implemented with **DeckGl**

I am trying to make my Pathlayer color changes on evenry mouse click (onClick), using **onClick**, **getColor**, **getFillColor**. As you see I have already the mechanism that detects that an item is clicked **selectedItem** which returns an object (with all item's infos) but the color change does not seem to work.

```
  const [selectedItem, setSelectedItem] = useState("");



  const layers = [
  new PathLayer({
  id: "CanalisationData",
  data: reseauData,
  pickable: true,
  widthScale: 3,
  widthMinPixels: 2,
  autoHighlight: true,
  highlightColor: [255, 255, 255],
  getPath: (d) => d.GEOJSON.coordinates,
  onHover: (info) => setHoverCanalisations(info),
  onClick: (d) => setSelectedItem(d.object),
  getColor: d => findColor(d), 

  getFillColor: d => selectedItem ? [255,0,0] : [119, 136, 153],
  updateTriggers: {
      getFillColor: [selectedItem]
  })],
```

My idea is to say to the code :

***if selectedItem*** ===> make the selected item look [255,0,0] color
***else*** ===> *just let it with the basic color*.

What Am I doing wrong ?

Edit : After *AdriSolid's* answer I have modified my PathLayer code like this, knowing that I get my **selectedItem** from a useState hook **setSelectedItem** that is linked to the **OnClick** just above :

```
  const [selectedItem, setSelectedItem] = useState("");


  const layers = [
  new PathLayer({
  id: "CanalisationData",
  data: reseauData,
  pickable: true,
  widthScale: 3,
  widthMinPixels: 2,
  autoHighlight: true,
  highlightColor: [255, 255, 255],
  getPath: (d)    => d.GEOJSON.coordinates,
  onHover: (info) => setHoverCanalisations(info),
  onClick: (d)    => setSelectedItem(d.object),
  getColor: d     => selectedItem?[255,200,0]: [119, 136, 153], 
  updateTriggers: {
    getColor: {selectedItem}
  },
}),
```

It seems like that my coe is not detecting that I am actually selecting an item,

`getFillColor: d => selectedItem ? [255,0,0] : [255, 255, 255],`

Doesn't seem to work.

Here is an image on my map, the objectif is to make the grays lines change color by clicking on each of them ...

[SCREENSHOT OF MY MAP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KdC4A.png)

Comment: `getFillColor` is not an accessor from `PathLayer`, you should use `getColor` instead. Do you want to change the color of a specific feature or the entire dataset?

Comment: Yes I want to change the color of a specific feature and after user's click (selectedTroncon is actually the state variable that says to me that a feature is clicked), also I have tried this but still doesn't work :

getColor: d     => selectedTroncon.NUMERO === d.NUMERO ? [255,200,0] :  findColor(d),

Comment: I just edited the original question, please see it

Comment: Please try to create a codepen with your issue